# How to check if a RTCPeerConnection is working?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I got a `RTCPeerConnection`, when the connection is established I want to disconnect from the web-server.

**How do I check for an established connection?**

`readyState` was always `undefined` and `onopen` never fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readyState` comes from an earlier version of the standard. You can now determine this from the [`PeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange` callback](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#widl-RTCPeerConnection-oniceconnectionstatechange) and by querying the [`PeerConnection.iceConnectionState`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#widl-RTCPeerConnection-iceConnectionState). The state value you're looking for is probably [`connected`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#rtciceconnectionstate-enum).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, is this for you?

```
if (typeof RTCPeerConnection == "undefined") {
  Abort("RTCPeerConnection is not supported/enabled in this browser, cannot test!");
}
```

or maybe set to `null` value to broke up a connection?

```
RTCPeerConnection = null;
```

Comment: no no. I already have a running connection. But I only see it in the browser, because it shows the streams. How do I get the information, that everything worked in JavaScript?